# Is there any way to check how large an SDF file will grow before adding a row to it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Consider this scenario:

- I have an application that uses SQL CE and adds rows of messages in an SDF file.
- I roll over to a new SDF file when one reaches a certain size (say, 100MB). Meaning, I archive the old SDF file since it hits this maximum, and start logging to a new SDF file until it, too, hits this maximum. This process repeats itself forever.
- BUT: I want to roll over before my SDF file reaches that size.

Is there any way to check how large my SDF file will grow to before actually adding a row to it?

Let's say this is the schema for it: 1 table named `MyMessages`, which contains only 1 column named `TheMessages` which is of type `VARCHAR(1000)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any way to do this, in addition the file may shrink when the last connection to the file is closed due to the autoshrink feature. You will have to accept a margin and check in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to approximate the overhead at all, like for example, assigning an approximate overhead size to each "shrunk" (compressed) character and then adding up the total, and checking if the total is above or below? Since, at least, I know I will not be changing the schema?

Comment: Strangely enough, from trial and error I found it works best to simply add up the size of all column datatypes except types such as strings, from which I just add the byte size of using System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount. Then, I multiply that sum by 2.

Comment: Just a small correction: "...add up the size *in bytes* of all column datatypes..."